# custom breadcrumb module not getting called from custom joomla component

Tags: module, joomla, components, breadcrumbs

Why my custom breadcrumb module is not getting called from my custom component?

I've written a custom breadcrumb module and now my navigation is correctly appearing : http://www.downloadformsindia.com/Provident-Fund-Forms/download-provident-fund-pf-epf-form-31.html?task=view

However there is one final download page which is my custom component, but in this it's not calling the custom breadcrumb module. So in this I'm showing the navigation in the Article area only by storing in sessions: 
See the custom component:http://www.downloadformsindia.com/index.php?option=com_download&e=n&task=showpage&file=Forms%2FEPFO-Forms%2Fpdf%2FEnglishHindiWithInstructions%2Fform31.pdf&title=Provident+Fund%2FPF%2FEPF+Form-31%3A+With+Instructions+without+Declaration&code=igi

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no menu item for the page where the breadcrumbs don't how up. For pages without a menu item to assign a module to, the only modules that will display are the ones set to display on All pages.

You need to either make a menu module for the page so you can assign the module to it, or you can use the Advance Module Manager: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/modules-management/10307. I highly recommend the Adv. Module Manager, it works perfectly and allows you a lot of options for module display.